# Conceptual doubt regarding Standing Waves, in particular constructing a Standing Wave after $t=T/2$ seconds

Tags: waves, time-evolution

Suppose you are given with the following figure:

[image]

And you have to sketch the shape of the standing wave after T/4 seconds where T denotes the Time period.

[image]

What will be the shape of the curve? As far as I understand Standing Waves, I know that the nodes will remain fixed. But what makes this problem hard is the fact that a standing wave, unlike a travelling wave does not move, so I can't just shift the curve to the left or right. This leads me to another related question, what will be the shape of the curve at t=T/2 and why?

Comment: You can shift it.   The nodes are still there, you just can't see them, and you can shift the plot.  Plot velocity rather than position and you will see what I mean

Answer (score 0):

After $\frac{T}{4}$ seconds, you curve will just be a horizontal line. After $\frac{T}{2}$ seconds, the shape will be the symmetric of the curve you drew with respect to the $x$-axis. See the second picture of the wikipedia link for a pictural description :

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standing_wave

Mathematically, a standing wave can be expressed as a function of the form $f(x)g(t)$, such as, for instance :

$\cos(\omega t) \cos(k x)$

The nodes of the wave are the places $x_n$ for which $\cos(k x_n) = 0$. You thus see that the vibrationnal states at each $x_n$ is $0$, whatever the value of time $t$ is.
On the other hand, you see that at $t = \frac{T}{4}$ we have $\cos(\omega t) = 0$, thus the wave is zero everywhere : it appears as a horizontal line.

Comment: Could you explain, how you came up with that answer?

Comment: Just edited my post.

Answer (score 0):

A standing wave is a superposition of travelling waves. There's a node because the travelling waves always cancel (sum=0) at that point.  Peaks occur where the travelling waves add; this sum is time-varying as the question suggests.

To solve, write out the two $A_j*\sin(\omega\tau + \phi)$ wave equations and solve the time-varying value at your selected location.